# Bluetooth GATT: Set value and flag field correct

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bluetooth-gatt, characteristics

i have some problems by understanding the flag field in Bluetooth characteristics.

For example the heart rate measurement characteristic:

[image: Characteristic]

And its flags:

[image: Flags]

According to my understanding, the first part of the value must contain the flags.
For example 0x06 for:

- Heart Rate Value Format is set to uint8
- Sensor Contact detected = true
- Sensor Contact Supported = true

The second part of the value is then byte(Heartrate).

In Python i fill the value like this:

```
value = []
value.append(dbus.Byte(0x06))
value.append(dbus.Byte(randint(90, 130)))
```

The whole thing also works perfectly. When I connect to the server with the app nRF connect I get all the info perfectly displayed with all the info.

Now about my problem:

I tried to implement the Weight Measurement Characteristic.

[image: Weight Measurement]

I want Weight in kg, BMI and height. So for my understanding i have to fill flag field with 0x08 for 00001000.

In Python it will look like this:

```
value = []
value.append(dbus.Byte(0x08))
value.append(dbus.Byte(randint(1, 13))) #weight
value.append(dbus.Byte(randint(1, 25))) #BMI
value.append(dbus.Byte(randint(1, 25))) #height
```

Now i get in nRF Connect App the message Invalid Data Syntax.

My Questions are:

1. How to handle with the resolution 0.0001? Value = Height/0.0001 or Height*0.0001?
2. What is meant by represented values M = 1, d=-1, ...?
3. Why is my Value in the second python code invalid?

Thank you very very much for your help!

I'm using bluez5.63/test/example-gatt-server.py for my Server!

Comment: In the `GATT Specification Supplement` document at https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/ Take a look at section "2.3 Values and represented values" where it explains about represented values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to build the value for a characteristic is to use the Python `struct` library to pack that values into bytes.

The values sent in the characteristics are always bytes which can only represent integers. So to turn the `height` value to an integer it is saying that for every increment of `1` on the field value, the hight value goes up by `0.001`. This means the decimal point needs to move 3 places to the right on the height value sent. So to send a height value of `0.001` you will actually send a value of `1`. This means your messurment needs to be multiplied by `value * 10**3` or if you prefer `value / 0.001`.

For weight it is similar but in addition to moving the decimal point you also have to change the value. This can be `value / 0.005` or  `value * (1 / 5) * 10 ** 3`

An example of how the python code might look:

```py
import struct

weight_char = struct.Struct('<BHHH')


def pack_flags(units, timestamp, user_id, bmi_height):
    flags = 0
    for idx, _flag in enumerate((units, timestamp, user_id, bmi_height)):
        flags |= _flag << idx
    return flags


flags = pack_flags(False, False, False, True)
weight = 42.4  # example weight in KG
height = 1.49  # Height in meters
bmi = 20.1

value = weight_char.pack(flags,
                         int(weight * 0.2 * 10**3),
                         int(bmi * 10**1),
                         int(height * 10**3))
print(f"Value to send: {value.hex()}")
```

Which gives the output of:

```
Value to send: 082021c900d205
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In my case i have to split these Bytes in dbus.Byte() elements to send the value, but this is just a small function!

Comment: I thought D-Bus did the correct thing if you passed a bytes object to the characteristic write... but maybe not. You could use a list comprehension... something like `[dbus.Byte(b) for b in value]`

Comment: i tried:
self.PropertiesChanged(GATT_CHRC_IFACE, { 'Value': value.hex() }, []) ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No error, but nothing in logs or on Screen in the nRF Connect app, so probably nothing arrives

Comment: and: 
self.PropertiesChanged(GATT_CHRC_IFACE, { 'Value': value }, [])
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Error:
Updating value: b'\x08\x08\x07x\x00\xf6\x06'
Traceback (most recent call last):
    self.PropertiesChanged(GATT_CHRC_IFACE, { 'Value': value }, [])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/decorators.py", line 325, in emit_signal
    message.append(signature=signature, *args)
ValueError: embedded null byte

Comment: OK, I didn't realise you were doing this with `ChangedProperties` which has the signature `@dbus.service.signal(DBUS_PROP_IFACE, signature='sa{sv}as')`. So you will need to define what dbus object it is inside the array.  Did `[dbus.Byte(b) for b in value]` work? i.e.  `self.PropertiesChanged(GATT_CHRC_IFACE, { 'Value': [dbus.Byte(b) for b in value]}, [])`